# Using a foreign key as part of a composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have two tables in SQL Server. The first is all the 1:1 relationships that belong to individual jobs, which has the primary key declared as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs(
JobNumber bigint PRIMARY KEY )
```

The second table is the list of all of the jobs' components and their 1:1 relationships.

Each component refers to a single job by its job number, which is a foreign key, and multiple components may refer to the same job. Components are numbered within jobs as 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Is it possible and reasonable to use the column `JobNumber` (foreign key) within a composite primary key in the 2nd table, so that the primary key would be made up of (`JobNumber, ComponentNumber`) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Components(
    JobNumber bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Jobs(JobNumber) NOT NULL,
    ComponentNumber int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(JobNumber, ComponentNumber) 
)
```

The other option is, of course, to use a surrogate primary key, but this would not enforce the uniqueness constraint on the combination of `JobNumber` and `ComponentNumber` (two records in the 2nd table could have `JobNumber=1` and `ComponentNumber=1`, for example), so I would prefer to use a composite natural primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not? I don't see any reason not to use the composite primary key!

The only *minor* drawback is that any other table that needs to reference your `Components` table now also **must use** both columns to establish a foreign key relationship - you cannot reference only half of the primary key of a table.

Also: if you would choose to use a separate surrogate column as your PK, you can always enforce uniqueness with a **unique constraint** on (`JobNumber, ComponentNumber`) ....